# AQL's PRUNE: How to combine conditions?

Tags: arangodb, aql

I am running ArangoDB `3.4.5` and I've been playing around with the `PRUNE` statements. I am having some difficulties combining conditions.

Assuming some vertices `v` on my path `p` have integer attributes `ia` and some `v` have boolean attributes `ba`. Even index `v` along `p` such as `p.vertices[2]` all have `ba`.

`PRUNE HAS(v, "ia") AND v.ia != 5`
works by itself.
`PRUNE p.vertices[2].ba == false OR p.vertices[4].ba == false`
also works by itself.

I observe, that I cannot combine them in one query, neither by multiple `PRUNE` statements nor by putting them in one
`PRUNE (condition_1) OR (condition_2)`. Also I cannot put one in a `PRUNE` and the next in a `FILTER` statement.
Is anyone else experiencing this or is it just me?

UPDATE:
The `FILTER` and `PRUNE` statements did not return the desired results, the reason was however the missing `OPTIONS {uniqueEdges: "none"}`. As opposed to the `uniqueVertices`, `none` is not default.

Comment: This looks pretty good, something like `PRUNE (HAS(v, "ia") AND v.ia !=5) OR (p.vertices[2].ba == false OR p.vertices[4].ba == false)` should do what you expect. At least, if the corresponding vertex consists of any such attribute that matches with this condition.

You will get the path with the vertex that matches the `PRUNE` condition but no further outgoing edges will get examined.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I finally found the issue on my side. What led to the confusion was that `OPTIONS {uniqueEdges: "none"}` is not default whereas `OPTIONS {uniqueVertices: "none"}` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your issue in ArangoDB 3.4.5
If you create collections `edge` and `vertex` and populate these with an example tree:

```
FOR n in 0..100000
  INSERT {_key: TO_STRING(n), val: n, modulo: n%2} INTO vertex
  FILTER n > 0
  INSERT {_from: CONCAT("vertex/", FLOOR((n-1)/2)), _to: NEW._id} INTO edge
```

Now I run a traversal:

```
WITH vertex
FOR v,e,p IN 0..5 OUTBOUND "vertex/0" edge
    RETURN TO_STRING(p.vertices[*].val)
```

Result:

```
   [
  "[0]",
  "[0,1]",
  "[0,1,3]",
  "[0,1,3,7]",
  "[0,1,3,7,15]",
  "[0,1,3,7,15,31]",
  "[0,1,3,7,15,32]",
  "[0,1,3,7,16]",
  "[0,1,3,7,16,33]",
  "[0,1,3,7,16,34]",
  "[0,1,3,8]",
  "[0,1,3,8,17]",
  "[0,1,3,8,17,35]",
  "[0,1,3,8,17,36]",
  "[0,1,3,8,18]",
  "[0,1,3,8,18,37]",
  "[0,1,3,8,18,38]",
  "[0,1,4]",
  ...
```

Next, I add `"stop": true` and `"hide": 1` to the vertex `_key: 7` and some other combinations to vertex 17 and 18. Now a PRUNE should stop traversing if the condition is meet. Be careful, the vertex itself is included in the results.

```
WITH vertex
FOR v,e,p IN 0..5 OUTBOUND "vertex/0" edge
  PRUNE v.hide == 1 AND v.stop == true
RETURN TO_STRING(p.vertices[*].val)
```

Result:

```
[
  "[0]",
  "[0,1]",
  "[0,1,3]",
  "[0,1,3,7]", <-- stop: true, hide: 1
  "[0,1,3,8]",
  "[0,1,3,8,17]", <-- stop: true, hide: 1
  "[0,1,3,8,18]",
  "[0,1,3,8,18,37]",
  "[0,1,3,8,18,38]", 
   ...
```

The PRUNE condition can use AND / OR, but just one PRUNE condition is supported (in contrast to FILTERS).

Comment: Thank you, this example proves it works as designed! I have finally found the issue on my side. See my previous comment and update.